# Shuffle by album disk in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, music, id3-tag

How I shuffle by disk in iTunes?

Would I mean is if an album has 5 disks,  I like each disk to treated as a separate album only for shuffling purposes.

I think setting the sort album  to  disk number i.e.  `album name disk 1` but this had no effect.

N.b.  this is **not** the same as shuffle by album.

Update:
Changing the album title would work  but this would mean in the album view I have the same album multiple times, so I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: Untested, but you might have to change the album names themselves to reflect which disk; then it will treat them separately.

Comment: That would work, but would mean in the album view I have the same album multiple times